# jQuery slider on external value change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that uses jQuery range(sliders) and returns the starting and the limit value of the range in two text boxes. This function works fine.

```
 function sliderRange () {
    var player = document.getElementById("audio-player");
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: player.duration,
        values: [0, player.duration],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#slider-value1").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#slider-value2").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#slider-value1").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));

    $("#slider-value2").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
```

I have this function, given the input in the text boxes,changes the sliders position:

```
$("input.slider-value").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#slider-range").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
});
```

My problem is that even though, it changes the sliders position to the new values, it doesn't update the value so my other functions ignore the new range and still use the old or the initial one to get data. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Please click the `<>` to create a [mcve]

Comment: Did my answer help you? Please, add some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In general your code looks good, you might have forgotten to define `data-index` attributes with your input-fields that are used to change either the `value1` or `value2` while a input-field is changed (`change`).

I provided a similar example that I hope will help you:

```js
function sliderRange() {
  $('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    values: [
      0,
      10
    ],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $('#slider-value1').val(ui.values[0]);
      $('#slider-value2').val(ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $('#slider-value1').val($('#slider').slider('values', 0));
  $('#slider-value2').val($('#slider').slider('values', 1));
}

sliderRange();

$('input.slider-value').change(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('#slider').slider('values', $this.data('index'), $this.val());
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="slider-value1" class="slider-value" data-index="0"/>
<input type="text" id="slider-value2" class="slider-value" data-index="1"/>

</body>
</html>
```